# python tkinter, how to get elements in root/notebook/Frame?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I use tkinter to create gui

```
1、root = tk.Tk()

2、tabControl = ttk.Notebook(root)
//create one notebook

3、tab1 = tk.Frame(tabControl, bg = 'blue', width = '400')
     tabControl.add(tab1, text = 'information')
//create one Frame in notebook

4、tree = ttk.Treeview(tab1,columns=ac)
//create one tree view in Frame
```

such as:
root
--notebook
----Frame
------tree

So, my question:

If I get root, How can I get elements in root?

For example, How can I get notebook/Frame/tree?

Thanks very much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try attribute `children`

```py
>>> root.children
{'!notebook': <tkinter.ttk.Notebook object .!notebook>}
>>> tabControl.children
{'!frame': <tkinter.Frame object .!notebook.!frame>}
>>> tab1.children
{'!treeview': <tkinter.ttk.Treeview object .!notebook.!frame.!treeview>}
>>> tree.children
{}
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I get tabControl from root.children?

Comment: `root.children['!notebook']`